# Build CSV with headers plus data out of JSON object

Tags: python, json, csv

I got the following problem with Python.

given the following JSON object - I would like to

- read this json as a dict
- take several of the keys and put them as a header in a CSV file like so:

CSV headers

```
firstName,lastName,managersEmail,contractStartsDate
```

- put the corresponding values of those keys inside the CSV as rows like so:

CSV contents

```
firstName,lastName,managersEmail,contractStartsDate
nameOfPerson,lastNameofPerson,someManager,2000-01-01
nameOfPerson2,lastNameofPerson2,someManager2,2000-02-02
```

- do not duplicate any keys inside the CSV
- but put each value from each key out of the JSON inside the CSV under the corresponding header value

my targetJSON.json

```
data = '{"details":[
{"firstName":"nameOfPerson,"lastName":"lastNameofPerson","managersEmail":"someEmail","managersName":"someManager",
    "departmentName":"someDepartment",
    "position":"somePosition",
    "contractStartsDate":"2000-01-01",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-01-01",
    "company":"someCompany",
    "division":"someDivision",
    "preferredName":"Unknown"},
{"firstName":"nameOfPerson2","lastName":"lastNameofPerson2","managersEmail":"someEmail2","managersName":"someManager2",
    "departmentName":"someDepartment2",
    "position":"somePosition2",
    "contractStartsDate":"2000-02-02",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-02-02",
    "company":"someCompany",
    "division":"someDivision2",
    "preferredName":"Unknown"}
]}'
```

My code looks like this

```
with open('targetJSON.json', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

for distro in distros_dict:
    print(distro['managersEmail'])


data_file = open("targetJSON.json", "r")
values = json.load(data_file)
data_file.close()

with open("usersData.csv", "wb") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    for data in values:
        value = data["managersEmail"]
        value = data["firstName"]
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            #wr.writerow([key, value])
            wr.writerow([key.encode("utf-8"), value.encode("utf-8")])
```

But the results is complete gibberish, 
the CSV contains everything mixed up :-(

Comment: When you say you want to avoid duplicate keys. Do you mean don't write a row if any of it's keys have been seen before.. Or just don't write duplicate rows?

Comment: "just don't write duplicate rows" would be correct I think.

Basically the JSON contains nested objects with all those keys + values. Per nested object there is 1x firstname 2x lastname (and so on) with the values. This jSOn can get huge with several 1000 nested objefts - each representing some real world object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `newline=""` when using a `csv.writer()` with Python 3.x, `wb` is used for Python 2.x versions.

Using the sample JSON you've given, you would just need to iterate over the header fields and create a row from each entry in `details`. For example:

```
import json
import csv

data = """{"details":[{"firstName":"nameOfPerson","lastName":"lastNameofPerson","managersEmail":"someEmail",
    "managersName":"someManager", "departmentName":"someDepartment", "position":"somePosition", "contractStartsDate":"2000-01-01",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-01-01", "company":"someCompany", "division":"someDivision", "preferredName":"Unknown"},
{"firstName":"nameOfPerson2","lastName":"lastNameofPerson2","managersEmail":"someEmail2","managersName":"someManager2",
    "departmentName":"someDepartment2", "position":"somePosition2", "contractStartsDate":"2000-02-02",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-02-02", "company":"someCompany", "division":"someDivision2", "preferredName":"Unknown"}
]}"""

json_data = json.loads(data)
header = ["firstName", "lastName", "managersEmail", "contractStartsDate"]

with open("usersData.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for entry in json_data["details"]:
        csv_output.writerow([entry[key] for key in header])
```

Giving you:

```
firstName,lastName,managersEmail,contractStartsDate
nameOfPerson,lastNameofPerson,someEmail,2000-01-01
nameOfPerson2,lastNameofPerson2,someEmail2,2000-02-02
```

If your JSON data contains duplicate entries, then you would have to first load all of the data and remove duplicates before starting to write the rows.

---

Alternatively, you could use a `csv.DictWriter` as follows:

```
import json
import csv

data = """{"details":[{"firstName":"nameOfPerson","lastName":"lastNameofPerson","managersEmail":"someEmail",
    "managersName":"someManager", "departmentName":"someDepartment", "position":"somePosition", "contractStartsDate":"2000-01-01",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-01-01", "company":"someCompany", "division":"someDivision", "preferredName":"Unknown"},
{"firstName":"nameOfPerson2","lastName":"lastNameofPerson2","managersEmail":"someEmail2","managersName":"someManager2",
    "departmentName":"someDepartment2", "position":"somePosition2", "contractStartsDate":"2000-02-02",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-02-02", "company":"someCompany", "division":"someDivision2", "preferredName":"Unknown"}
]}"""

json_data = json.loads(data)
fieldnames = ["firstName", "lastName", "managersEmail", "contractStartsDate"]

with open("usersData.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction="ignore")
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(json_data["details"])
```

---

To read the data from an input JSON file, you can do the following:

```
import json
import csv

with open("sourceJSON.json", encoding="utf-8") as f_input:
    json_data = json.load(f_input)

fieldnames = ["firstName", "lastName", "managersEmail", "contractStartsDate"]

with open("usersData.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction="ignore")
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerows(json_data["details"])
```

If you need to remove identical rows, then replace the last line with:

```
csv_output.writerows(dict(t) for t in {tuple(entry.items()) : '' for entry in json_data["details"]})
```

Comment: Woha! Thank you for this. Going to try it out now and checking my Python versions.. I probably do not need 2.x but fear of removing it..currently my script works on 2.x I guess..and I have to learn more :D

Comment: Your print statement implies you are using Python 3.x, so it should be fine.

Comment: all working :)
I am figuring out this right now:

my JSON will be in a .json file and my python script needs to read the file, do its logic then build the csv (which is gonna be read by some other script later)

so I need to to read a huge-ass json file - possibly 20 mb big and then make the CSV

Comment: getting tracebacks :(

Comment: With the script "as is" or have you made changes?  Note, your JSON was missing a close `"` for `"nameOfPerson"`

Comment: Basically as is. In my JSON file the object itself looks like this:
´´´
data = '{"details":[
{"firstName":"nameOfPerson","lastName":"lastNameofPerson","managersEmail":"someEmail","managersName":"someManager",
    "departmentName":"someDepartment",
    "position":"somePosition",
    "contractStartsDate":"2000-01-01",
    "contractEndDate":"2000-01-01",
    "company":"someCompany",
    "division":"someDivision",
    "preferredName":"Unknown"}
]}'
´´´

So I am just struggling to read the file with "data" as the name of the complete object.

Comment: To help further, you'd need to show me the traceback you are getting, and probably give me a link to the full JSON file you are using.

Comment: Will do so when I am totally stuck! Thank you Martin for all the help

Comment: Unfortuantely I cannot show my files.

Let me ask this way:

How do you tell python to put the contents of a file file.json into the variable "data" just like in your script but the contents of "data" is in a file - not in the script

Comment: OK It must have to do with all the quotes around my objects.

So putting my real json inside the script and surrounding it with 3 quotes works and results in my CSV having exactly what I need.

Now lets try again with only the file

Comment: Your JSON file should start `{"details":` and end `"preferredName":"Unknown"}
]}`   I have updated the script to show you how to read the JSON from a source file.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 64, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(f)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper

Comment: I tried it and it worked like a charm. Thank you once again for the superb help.

Honestly this feels like cheating but I need this for work..
I will implement some more logic to get the desired data out of my huge json - some lookups for startDate and so on.

Cheers!